# How to get array from string without using dividers(split()), just to get the whole string and convert it to an array type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, types

For, example, I have the following string

```
var str = '[new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1],[new Date(2014, 1, 1), 2],[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]';
```

The question is how to convert the string type into an array, as it's actually an array wrapped in a string quotes.

The expected result needs be the following:

```
var res = [[new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1],[new Date(2014, 1, 1), 2],[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just `eval`...?

Comment: what  did you try? array of what expected ?

Comment: @NinaScholz Eval returns Mon Dec 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300. Not returning as it is. I mean `new Date(2014, 0, 1)` etc.

Comment: str is not actually a stringified array - it is 3 arrays - pretty sure unless you cannot modify the string to wrap it in a single array eval will not return 3 arrays that you could wrap in a new array

Comment: I have added a expected result, please take a look.

Comment: the result is not valid.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's a Javascript array, everything is valid there.

Comment: no, you have three arrays, but not wrapped in an array.

Comment: @NinaScholz I even pasted into the Chrome console, it works perfectly, what are you talking about ? :)

Comment: @NinaScholz I updated the res variable, wrapped in an array `[]`, will this fix the issue somehow ?

Comment: yes, now it's valid. and my answer is valid as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz I am sorry, what it's not valid. The console returns this ["[new Date(2014, 0, 1), -1],[new Date(2014, 1, 1),  2],[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]"]

But should return like this: [[new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1],[new Date(2014, 1, 1), 2],[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]]

Comment: @NinaScholz You see the difference ?

Comment: you can not have `new Date` in an array. this is code. the result is a data object.

Comment: What do you want to archive with that? Maybe we could help you with your larger goal. The expected result is not a valid JavaScript-array. It will create an array of dates and not contain 'new Date(...)'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the data, take `eval` with wrapped array.

```js
var str = '[new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1],[new Date(2014, 1, 1), 2],[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]',
    array = eval(`[${str}]`);

console.log(array[0][0].constructor === Date);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: It needs to be returned as is in the string: `new Date(2014, 0, 1)` and not "2013-12-31T20:00:00.000Z".

Comment: please add the wanted result to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Your string is not an array - if you can add array markers to it then you can simply eval(str)

```
var str = '[[new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1],[new Date(2014, 1, 1), 2],[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]]';
console.log(eval(str));
// outputs: 
0: [Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), 1]
1: [Sat Feb 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), 2]
2: [Sat Mar 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), 3]
```

Comment: It needs to return an array [new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1],[new Date(2014, 1, 1), 2],[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]

Comment: but if you return an array this will evaluate new Date() to be a resultant date - the only place the literal string `new Date()` can be preserved is in source code or a string - the minute you convert to a JS array it will be evaluated

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the `str` variable that you have shared above is not an array of arrays.

Your variable basically is

```
var str = '
[new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1],
[new Date(2014, 1, 1), 2],
[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]
';
```

So, if you run `eval` on the above variable it will simply evaluate the first array it sees and it returns the result. However, if you convert your above string to an array of arrays, then it will traverse through all arrays and give you your expected result.

```js
var str = '[new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1],[new Date(2014, 1, 1), 2],[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]'; //Your string

let arr1 = eval(str);

console.log("arr1 with no array of arrays", arr1); 

let str2 = '[[new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1],[new Date(2014, 1, 1), 2],[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]]'; //Do note the extra square brackets at the start and at the end.

let arr2 = eval(str2);

console.log("arr2 with array of arrays", arr2);
```

I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: It needs to return an array [new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1],[new Date(2014, 1, 1), 2],[new Date(2014, 2, 1), 3]

Comment: Lots of misinformation given in deleted comments. Downvotes mean that an answer is unclear, not useful, or incorrect. That's what the tooltip on the downvote arrow means. Upvotes mean the opposite. You should not hesitate to vote answers up or down, depending on how helpful you find them. Voting is *anonymous*, so it shouldn't be discussed. Do not let anyone attack you for voting. Please flag all such comments for moderator attention.